# Radius of convergence for $\sum_{k} \frac{(-1)^kx^{k+1}}{k+1}+\sum_{k } \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Say I want to find the radius of convergence for $\displaystyle \sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kx^{k+1}}{k+1}+\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$

Ratio test gives me $$ R = \lim_{k \to \infty} \bigg|\frac{\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+1}}{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+2}}\bigg| = \lim_{k \to \infty}\bigg|\frac{[(-1)^{k+1}-1](k+1)}{[(-1)^k-1](k+2)}\bigg|$$

What's wrong with this reasoning: we can't have $(-1)^k-1 = 0$; in other words, $k$ cannot be even. If $k$ is odd, $(-1)^{k+1}-1 = 0$, so $R = 0?$! And how do I find the radius of convergence for this?

Comment: The ratio test is not so great when half your terms are zero.  You could rewrite the series to have only nonzero terms and then apply the ratio test to that.  A second point to note on the ratio test: you missed an $x$ in the ratio, which will become $x^2$ if you follow the first suggestion.

Comment: @ForgotALot I thought the formula $R = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right|$ did not involve $x$?

Comment: You have *two* series. You can apply the ratio test (or any other test) to them seperately.

Comment: The ratio test that I'm familiar with applies to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  c_n$, so any $x^n$ is part of the $c_n$.  See Baby Rudin 3.34.  There may be other versions of the ratio test that I've forgotten (see username) or never knew.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kx^{k+1}}{k+1}+\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=2\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$